# FFmpeg: Error while opening decoder for input stream #0:0 : Invalid argument

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

Hi I'm trying to transcode a `hevc` stream to `h264` using `ffmpeg`

`$ ffmpeg -c:v hevc_v4l2m2m -i video.mkv -c:v h264_v4l2m2m -c:a aac out.mp4`

I want to `ffmpeg` to explicitly decode the input `hevc` video using `hevc_v4l2m2m` API, and later encode the video to `h264 codec` using `h264_v4l2m2m` API.

However when I do this, `ffmpeg` throws the following error:

```
[hevc_v4l2m2m @ 0x556a56fcb0] Could not find a valid device
[hevc_v4l2m2m @ 0x556a56fcb0] can't configure decoder
Stream mapping: Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (hevc (hevc_v4l2m2m) -> h264 (h264_v4l2m2m))
Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy) Error while opening decoder for input stream #0:0 : Invalid argument
```

Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try this: `ffmpeg -c:v hevc_v4l2m2m -i video.mkv -c:v h264_v4l2m2m -c:a copy out.mp4`

Comment: @SaaranshGarg I get this error `[hevc_v4l2m2m @ 0x556a56fcb0] Could not find a valid device
[hevc_v4l2m2m @ 0x556a56fcb0] can't configure decoder
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (hevc (hevc_v4l2m2m) -> h264 (h264_v4l2m2m))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Error while opening decoder for input stream #0:0 : Invalid argument`

Comment: Are you using Raspberry Pi 4 ? I don't have experience with FFmpeg on Raspberry Pi, but it looks `hevc_v4l2m2m` is not a decoder. For getting a list of all FFmpeg decoders execute: `ffmpeg -decoders`.

Comment: @Rotem Yes I'm using raspberry pi 4. `hevc_v4l2m2m` is present on list of decoders
`pi@rpi4:~ $ ffmpeg -decoders | grep hevc`
 `V..... hevc_v4l2m2m         V4L2 mem2mem HEVC decoder wrapper (codec hevc)`

Comment: Are you sure that all streams are encoded in h265? Also check that your device supports h265 decoding in both hard and software. You might want to try `ffmpeg  -i video.mkv -c:v h264_v4l2m2m -c:a copy out.mp4` to check if h264 hardware encoding is possible. You could could always resort to software de-/encoding with `ffmpeg -i video.mkv -c:v libx264 -c:a copy out.mkv`

Comment: @mashuptwice Raspberry Pi 4 supports h264 hardware encoding and it worked. Looks like I have to resort to software decoding for h265

Comment: @user89978 Unfortunately the info about the Pis h265 capabilities is very thin, I could not find anything helpful

Comment: @user89978 `Could not find a valid device` Sounds like a driver issue to me. Does it even work when you only use it for encoding?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that all streams are encoded in h265? Also check that your device supports h265 decoding in both hard and software. You might want to try

```
ffmpeg  -i video.mkv -c:v h264_v4l2m2m -c:a copy out.mp4
```

to check if h264 hardware encoding is possible. You could could always resort to software de-/encoding with

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -c:v libx264 -c:a copy out.mkv
```